# Tuple conversion to a string

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
[('Steve Buscemi', 'Mr. Pink'), ('Chris Penn', 'Nice Guy Eddie'), ...]
```

I need to convert it to a string in the following format:

```
"(Steve Buscemi, Mr. Pink), (Chris Penn, Nice Guy Eddit), ..."
```

I tried doing

```
str = ', '.join(item for item in items)
```

but run into the following error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found
```

How would I do the above formatting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
', '.join('(' + ', '.join(i) + ')' for i in L)
```

Output:

```
'(Steve Buscemi, Mr. Pink), (Chris Penn, Nice Guy Eddie)'
```

Answer (score 5):

You're close.

```
str = '(' + '), ('.join(', '.join(names) for names in items) + ')'
```

Output:

```
'(Steve Buscemi, Mr. Pink), (Chris Penn, Nice Guy Eddie)'
```

Breaking it down: The outer parentheses are added separately, while the inner ones are generated by the first `'), ('.join`. The list of names inside the parentheses are created with a separate `', '.join`.

Comment: I like this solution! It avoids redundant string concatenation for each tuple with `+` operator as in my solution (which leads to recreation of string after each operation). In your solution this concatenation happens only on the last step after all joins.

Comment: @ovgolovin, I think yours is easier to follow which is why I added the breakdown. You deserve the checkmark.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = ', '.join( '(%s)'%(', '.join(item)) for item in items )
```

Comment: This gives `'(, <, g, e, n, e, r, a, t, o, r,  , o, b, j, e, c, t,  , <, g, e, n, e, x, p, r, >,  , a, t,  , 0, x, b, 7, 2, 0, 5, c, 3, 4, >, )'`. :^)

Comment: @DSM -- Only if you put the parenthesis that I missed in the wrong location (at the end).  I've updated and fixed it.

Comment: yep.  Not the first time I've done that, actually -- for some reason I always assume missing things go at the end, which has led to bugs on more than one occasion. :-/

Comment: I also removed a unnecessary genexp ... duh.

Comment: I think this is a tad simpler: `', '.join('(%s, %s)' % item for item in items)`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- You're right, but it assumes that each item only has 2 elements.

Comment: @mgilson:  True.  As long as each actor in Resevoir Dogs has a single role we're ok.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- And I suppose that they also need to be tuples, but that could be worked around with unpacking  `', '.join('(%s, %s)'%(actor,role) for actor,role in movie_list)`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
print str(items)[1:-1].replace("'", '') #Removes all apostrophes in the string
```

You want to omit the first and last characters which are the square brackets of your list. As mentioned in many comments, this leaves single quotes around the strings. You can remove them with a `replace`.

**NB** As noted by @ovgolovin this will **remove all apostrophes, even those in the names**.

Comment: This solution leaves tickmarks inside parenthesis: `"('Steve Buscemi', 'Mr. Pink'), ('Chris Penn', 'Nice Guy Eddie')"`

Comment: "I need to convert it to a string" - this answer, while simple, doesn't fit the requirements.

Comment: This answer is good, but doesn't strip the single quotes inside the string, which I need to do.

Comment: @DSM Damn, you are all right, I was sure there was quotes on the model. Fixed with a simple replace.

Comment: I see your update. What if apostrophe is inside one of the string? It'll be removed.

Comment: @ovgolovin They are no apostrophe inside any name of 'Reservoir Dogs' characters?

Answer (score 0):

you were close...

```
print ",".join(str(i) for i in items)
```

or

```
print str(items)[1:-1]
```

or

```
print ",".join(map(str,items))
```

Comment: Also note that this will have a bunch of extra quotes in it.